# How can I deal with this Error: not found: YoutubeDL?

Tags: error-handling, terminal, yt-dlp

I wanted to run this project https://github.com/mayeaux/generate-subtitles , but when i do npm start i get this :throw getNotFoundError(cmd)
^

Error: not found: YoutubeDL
at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\Otilia\Downloads\generate-subtitles-master\generate-subtitles\node_modules\which\lib\index.js:16:17)
at AsyncFunction.whichSync [as sync] (C:\Users\Otilia\Downloads\generate-subtitles-master\generate-subtitles\node_modules\which\lib\index.js:106:9)
at Object. (C:\Users\Otilia\Downloads\generate-subtitles-master\generate-subtitles\downloading\yt-dlp-download.js:11:25)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\Otilia\Downloads\generate-subtitles-master\generate-subtitles\routes\api.js:12:41) {
code: 'ENOENT'                                                                                               I have installed yt-dlp(when i do pip install it is already satisfied)

so yea idkwhat to do

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp.exe.
Next I renamed yt-dlp.exe to YoutubeDL.exe.
And added file location to the PATH.